# Calculate and create time duration from DATETIME using DISTINCT records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I have a very large temporal data set showing power outages for the entire US over a 2-year span. I want to calculate the duration of an outage using distinct records from 4 columns. The '0' value for CustomersOut is seen as reset.

Example:

```
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 0, 2017-12-28 12:25:00
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 50, 2018-01-01 03:25:00
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 65, 2018-01-01 03:36:00
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 40, 2018-01-01 03:55:00
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 0, 2018-01-01 04:34:00
```

This means in City1, there were 50 customers out for 11 min, 65 out for 19 min, and 40 out for 39 min, for a total of 55.75 customer hours out.

Desired Result:

```
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 0, 2017-12-28 12:25:00, NULL
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 50, 2018-01-01 03:25:00, 00:11.00
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 65, 2018-01-01 03:36:00, 00:19.00
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 40, 2018-01-01 03:55:00, 00:39.00
Utility1, State1, County1, City1, 1500, 0, 2018-01-01 04:34:00, NULL
```

[image: Table Image]

Comment: "TIMESTAMP" is a deprecated data type that has nothing to do with dates or times. I think you mean to say "datetime" here. It's important to understand this distinction.

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thank you for the correction

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the comment. Post has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with a subquery that computes the difference between the current record and the next one. Then, the outer query filters on records that correspond to power outages and aggregates:

```
select 
     UtilityName, 
     StateName, 
     CountyName, 
     CityName,
     sum(CustomersOut) CustomersOut,
     sum(MinutesOut) MinutesOut,
     sum(CustomersOut * MinutesOut) / 60.0 CustomersHoursOut
from (
    select 
        UtilityName, 
        StateName, 
        CountyName,
        CityName,
        CustomersOut,
        datediff(
            minute,
            RecordedDateTime,
            lead(RecordedDateTime) over(
                partition by UtilityName, StateName, CountyName, CityName 
                order by RecordedDateTime
            )
        ) MinutesOut
    from mytable 
) t
where CustomersOut > 0
group by
     UtilityName, 
     StateName, 
     CountyName, 
     CityName
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=414129af2f2a879724d75e80a6956b70)**:

```
UtilityName | StateName | CountyName | CityName | CustomersOut | MinutesOut | CustomersHoursOut
:---------- | :-------- | :--------- | :------- | -----------: | ---------: | :------------------
Utility1    | State1    | County1    | City1    |          155 |         69 | 55.750000
```

**EDIT**

The information that you want can be generated from the inner query:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when CustomersOut > 0
    then datediff(
        minute,
        RecordedDateTime,
        lead(RecordedDateTime) over(
            partition by UtilityName, StateName, CountyName, CityName 
            order by RecordedDateTime
        )
    ) 
    end MinutesOut
from mytable t
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2415c6f35c9208e1ef1711ec80501661)**:

```
UtilityName | StateName | CountyName | CityName | CustomersTracked | CustomersOut | RecordedDateTime    | MinutesOut
:---------- | :-------- | :--------- | :------- | ---------------: | -----------: | :------------------ | ---------:
Utility1    | State1    | County1    | City1    |             1500 |            0 | 2017-12-28 12:25:00 |       null
Utility1    | State1    | County1    | City1    |             1500 |           50 | 2018-01-01 03:25:00 |         11
Utility1    | State1    | County1    | City1    |             1500 |           65 | 2018-01-01 03:36:00 |         19
Utility1    | State1    | County1    | City1    |             1500 |           40 | 2018-01-01 03:55:00 |         39
Utility1    | State1    | County1    | City1    |             1500 |            0 | 2018-01-01 04:34:00 |       null
```

Comment: . . Now that the OP has updated the question, you can just remove the `GROUP BY`.